# Django: Easiest way to join all numerical data into one QuerySet when doing alphabetical pagination?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to sort query results into alphabetical sections, like so:

[image]

This works with the following code:

```
    def get_context(self, request):
        # Get published shows, ordered alphabetically
        context = super().get_context(request)
        shows = ShowPage.objects.child_of(self).live().order_by("name")
        context["pages"] = [{"letter" : i, 
                            "shows" : shows.filter(name__istartswith=i.upper())}
                            for i in "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"]
        return context
```

The next step is to combine all shows that start with any number into just one group labeled "0-9".

The following does what I want, but it's awfully verbose and I'm wondering if there's an easier way I just don't know about:

```
def get_context(self, request):
        # Get published shows, ordered alphabetically
        context = super().get_context(request)
        shows = ShowPage.objects.child_of(self).live().order_by("name")
        pages = [{"letter" : i, 
                            "shows" : shows.filter(name__istartswith=i.upper())}
                            for i in "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"]
        digits = {"letter" : "0 - 9", "shows" : []}
        for index, alphabet in enumerate(pages):
            if alphabet["letter"].isdigit():
                for show in alphabet["shows"]:
                    digits["shows"] += [show]
        while pages[0]["letter"].isdigit():
            print(pages[0])
            pages.pop(0)
        pages.insert(0, digits)
        context["pages"] = pages
        return context
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an easy one-line of regex in the field search to see if the name string starts with a digit. Also `istartswith` is case-insensitive so you don't need the `i.upper()`.

```
def get_context(self, request):
        # Get published shows, ordered alphabetically
        context = super().get_context(request)
        shows = ShowPage.objects.child_of(self).live().order_by("name")
        context['pages'] = [{'letter': shows.filter(name__istartswith=letter)} for letter in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']
        context['pages'].append({'letter': '0-9', 'shows': shows.filter(name__regex=r'^\d[\w\d _-]+'})
        return context
```